# Application of Markov's inequality

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

let  $h\colon \mathbb{R} \to [0,\alpha]$ be a nonnegative bounded function. Show that for $0\leq a<\alpha$ that the following holds:

\begin{equation}
Pr(h(X)\leq a) \geq \frac{E[h(X)]-a}{\alpha-a}
\end{equation}

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 2):

Let $Y=h(X)$. Since $Y\leqslant\alpha$ almost surely, $(\alpha-a)\mathbf 1_{Y\leqslant a}\leqslant\alpha-Y$ almost surely. Integrating this pointwise inequality yields
$$
P[Y\leqslant a]\leqslant\frac{\alpha-E[Y]}{\alpha-a}.
$$
Equivalently,
$$
P[Y\geqslant a]\geqslant\frac{E[Y]-a}{\alpha-a}.
$$
*Nota:* The inequality in the post cannot hold since, when $h(X)\to\alpha$ in probability, the LHS converges to $0$ and the RHS converges to $1$.